# pickle error when serialize cython class with lambda

Tags: python, lambda, cython, pickle, dill

I use pickle and dill for follow lambda function and work fine :

```
import dill
import pickle

f = lambda x,y: x+y
s = pickle.dumps(f)
```

or even when used in class, for example:

file

> **foo.py**

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = lambda x, y: x+y
```

file

> **test.py**

```
import dill
import pickle
from foo import Foo

f = Foo()
s = pickle.dumps(f)  # or  s = dill.dumps(f)
```

but when build same file with format **.pyx** (foo.pyx) using cython, can't serialize with dill, pickle or cpickle, get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2878, in run_cod
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       a = pickle.dumps(c)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1380, in dumps
>       Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
>       self.save(obj)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
>       self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
>       save(state)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
>       f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 912, in save_module_dict
>       StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
>       self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 669, in _batch_setitems
>       save(v)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 317, in save
>       self.save_global(obj, rv)
>     File "/home/amin/anaconda2/envs/rllab2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 754, in save_global
>       (obj, module, name))
>   PicklingError: Can't pickle . at 0x7f9ab1ff07d0>: it's not found as foo.lambda

**setup.py file for build cython**

> **setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("foo.pyx"))
```

then run in terminal:

> python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Is there a way ?

Comment: `pickle` is already complied code.  What do you how to accomplish with `cython`?

Comment: @hpaulj 
i just compiled my class (foo.pyx) not file contain pickle (test.py) and when i dont use lambda in foo.pyx class, this is work fine just get error when use lambda.

Comment: @kiba Realistically this isn't going to work. A Cython lambda isn't the same as a Python lambda, and I don't think any effort has been made to make it pickle-able. Generally lambdas will have some closure variables and I imagine those are especially non-pickleable in Cython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  Expanding on what @DavidW says in the comments -- I believe there are (currently) no known serializers that can pickle cython lambdas, or the vast majority of cython code. Indeed, it is much more difficult for python serializers to be able to pickle objects with C-extensions unless the authors of the C-extension code specifically build serialization instructions (as did `numpy` and `pandas`).  In that vein... instead of a lambda, you could build a class with a `__call__` method, so it acts like a function... and then add one or more of the pickle methods (`__reduce__`, `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`, or something similar)... and then you should be able to pickle instances of your class. It's a bit of work, but since this path has been used to pickle classes written in C++ -- I believe you should be able to get it to work for cython-built classes.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```py
import dill
import pickle

f = lambda x,y: x+y
s = pickle.dumps(f)
```

`f` is a function,
But in another code

```py
import dill
import pickle
from foo import Foo

f = Foo()
s = pickle.dumps(f)  
# or  
s = dill.dumps(f)
```

`f` is a class